# R: Print ALL Longest Increasing Subsequences (LIS)

Tags: r, dynamic, lis

Given a vector

```
x <- c(4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,6)
```

Find ALL the longest increasing subsequences (LIS)

The solution should look like

```
4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14

4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,15
```

I could even do with the index of the elements

I've used the code given by [JINJING XIE](https://www.mango-solutions.com/blog/compute-longest-increasing-decreasing-subsequence-using-rcpp) but it only returns one sequence

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Here is a (slow & not very efficient) function that will compute it (uses `RcppAlgos`)

```
max_sub_sequences <- function (x) {  
  # x incresing, result is obviously x
  if (all(diff(x) > 0)) return (x)
  N <- length(x)
  n <- N - 1L 
  break_condition <- TRUE
  while (break_condition) {
    # generate all combinations of indices
    combinations <- RcppAlgos::comboGeneral(1:N,n)    
    # get subsequences according to indices
    sub_sequences <- matrix(x[combinations[1:nrow(combinations),]], nrow = nrow(combinations)) ; rm(combinations)
    # check monotony 
    index_subsequence <- vapply(1:nrow(sub_sequences), function (k) any(diff(sub_sequences[k,]) < 1L), logical(1L))
    # keep increasing sequences only
    sub_sequences <- sub_sequences[!index_subsequence,] ; rm(index_subsequence)
    break_condition <- nrow(sub_sequences) == 0L
    n <- n - 1L
  }
  sub_sequences
 }
max_sub_sequences(c(4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,6))    
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
# [1,]    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12    13    15
# [2,]    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12    13    14  

# timing
# Unit: seconds
#                 expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# max_sub_sequences(x) 1.30611 1.462473 1.502727 1.484785 1.522796 1.821037   100
```

There are for sure ways to make it more efficient, e.g. other logic or by writing it in `c++` and using `Rcpp` for the whole task.

Comment: Thanks! Works well and you're right, it is a little slow. I'm trying to keep the computation time as low as possible. Appreciate the help.

Comment: It will also fail for large vectors cause of memory limitations `x <- (18,19,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,9,10,12,13,14,15,16,17,19,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,18,19,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)`

Comment: @jonnyblue8 Yes I noticed, it is especially bad for large vectors with very little monotonicity. The best way to go is probably to edit the code you found so that it returns all values (or find an algorithm) and then implement it in `Rcpp` for efficiency. I'll edit my answer, should I manage to come with something.